# Access SQL calculations

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

Fairly new to MS Access SQL and trying to calculate as follows but not getting any meaningful results.

```
SELECT *
FROM file_name
WHERE ([Column_A] + Column_B + Column_C) - (Column_D + Column_E + Column_F) < > [Column_H];
```

Any guidance on this is appreciated

Thanks all. The image has sample data. The actual file has a million records. I have to extract the records similar to the two in red from the actual file using the above script.

Comment: share sample data and and expected output

Comment: Your query looks to be valid syntax.  You might want to add sample data (and the current/expected output) to your question.

Comment: is your issue adding null value with a not null value in sql.

Comment: @Gauravsa, my issue is that on running that script I am getting no records in the output file, when I can see there are records in the input file which should be picked up using this script.  Did I answer your question clearly? Sorry, very new to this so may not be very clear.

Comment: @JP_Ostrayla image is discourage to add in question ,however what will be in output from this sample data,according to your where clause all the 3 column will come to output

Comment: @Zaynul, apologies for that and appreciate your guidance. I hope to keep this mind going forward The output will be a file with all the columns from the input file and the two records in red text. Did I answer your question properly? Thanks again

Comment: If you leave out the WHERE clause, do you get results? What are the column names (your image shows both "Column A" and "Opening Debt")?

Comment: @Hans, thanks for your recommendation. I tried but it didn't work. On the subject of column name, my bad! The Column A....Column H is simply to link the column names in the original post to the actual column names which are , 'Opening Debt...…..Closing Debt'.  Please do let me know if I have not responded clearly to your enquiry. Thanks again.

Comment: If by "didn't work" you mean that you didn't get any data (using `SELECT *
FROM file_name`), then you will need to investigate that! It probably means that you are selecting from the wrong table (file?).

Comment: Does your actual query include `< >` (including the space) instead of `<>` (no space included)?

Comment: @Hans Keﬆing, I can confirm on removing the 'WHERE' clause, the script works fine.

Comment: @HansUp , it's without space. thanks

Comment: Even doing SELECT Client_id, Opening_Debt + New_Debt1 + New_Debt2 FROM file_name; I am not getting any results. The data type is 'CURRENCY' for the values in these fields.

Comment: Do you get any results with this? `SELECT Client_id, Nz(Opening_Debt, 0) + Nz(New_Debt1, 0) + Nz(New_Debt2, 0) FROM file_name;`

Comment: @HansUp, that worked!! And I was able to extend that to the remaining three columns. Thank you so much :)